# Transaction is not working in nested for loop

Tags: c#, transactions, oledb, firebird

I need 3 insert operation in Transaction. 2 Insert operation has for loop
first loop insert operation is working. But second, for loop insert operation is not working.

I'm using for in for loop, but it doesn't commit the result of the innumerable for the loop when it makes a transaction commit.

My Code

```
            // Set the Connection to the new OleDbConnection.
            command.Connection = connection;

            // Open the connection and execute the transaction.
            try
            {
                connection.Open();

                // Start a local transaction
                transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

                // Assign transaction object for a pending local transaction.
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.Transaction = transaction;

                // Execute the commands.
                command.CommandText =
                    @"INSERT INTO STOKASIL (STOK_ISLEMA_NO,ISLEM_KODU, ISLEM_YONU, ISLEM_ADI, GIRIS_CARI_NO, CIKIS_CARI_NO, GIRIS_STOK_YERI_NO,
                                                      CIKIS_STOK_YERI_NO, GIRIS_ISLEM_NOKTASI_NO, CIKIS_ISLEM_NOKTASI_NO, GIRIS_PERSONEL_NO, 
                                                        CIKIS_PERSONEL_NO,FATURA_NO,TARIH)

                                VALUES(" + stokAsil.IslemANo + ",'STKGİR', 1, 'Stok Girişi', " + stokAsil.GirisCariNo + ", " + stokAsil.CikisCariNo + @", 
                                        " + stokAsil.GirisStokYeriNo + @", 
                                        " + stokAsil.CikisStokYeriNo + @", 
                                        " + stokAsil.GirisIslemNoktasiNo + @",
                                        " + stokAsil.CikisIslemNoktasiNo + @", 
                                        " + stokAsil.GirisPersonelNo + @",
                                        " + stokAsil.CikisPersonelNo + @",
                                        '" + stokAsil.FaturaNo + @"',CURRENT_DATE)";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                for (int i = 0; i < stokAsil.StokIslm.Count; i++)
                {
                    command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO STOKISLM(STOK_ISLEMA_NO, ISLEM_KODU, ISLEM_ADI, ISLEM_YONU, TARIH,STOK_YERI_NO, 
                                                             CARI_NO, PERSONEL_NO, ISLEM_NOKTASI_NO, STOK_NO, BIRIM,BIRIMX,MIKTAR, 
                                                             DSTOK_NO, DOVIZ_BIRIMI, DOVIZ_KURU, TAKIP_SEKLI , FSTOK_URET)

                                       VALUES(" + stokAsil.IslemANo + @", 'STKGİR', 'Stok Girişi', 1, CURRENT_DATE, 
                                              " + stokAsil.StokIslm.ElementAt(i).StokYeriNo + @", " + stokAsil.StokIslm.ElementAt(i).CariNo + @", 
                                              " + stokAsil.StokIslm.ElementAt(i).PersonelNo + @",
                                              " + stokAsil.StokIslm.ElementAt(i).IslemNoktasıNo + @",
                                              " + stokAsil.StokIslm.ElementAt(i).StokNo + @",  
                                             (SELECT FIRST 1 BIRIM FROM STOKBIRI WHERE STOK_NO = " + stokAsil.StokIslm.ElementAt(i).StokNo + @" ORDER BY SIRA_NO), 
                                             (SELECT FIRST 1 BIRIMX FROM STOKBIRI WHERE STOK_NO = " + stokAsil.StokIslm.ElementAt(i).StokNo + @" ORDER BY SIRA_NO),
                                             " + stokAsil.StokIslm.ElementAt(i).Miktar + ", 0, 'TL', 1, 'M', 'E')";
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    for (int j = 0; j < stokAsil.StokIslm.ElementAt(i).TakipNo.Count(); j++)
                    {
                        command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO STOKCEKI (STOK_ISLEM_NO, TAKIP_NO,SIRA_NO ,MIKTAR,BIRIM, ACIKLAMA2, ACIKLAMA3,  ACIKLAMA4, ACIKLAMA5)
                                              VALUES(" + stokAsil.StokIslm.ElementAt(i).StokIslemNo + ", '" + stokAsil.StokIslm.ElementAt(i).TakipNo.ElementAt(j) + @"'," + j + 1 + @" ,
                                              " + stokAsil.StokIslm.ElementAt(i).Miktar + ", 'Adet' , '" + stokAsil.StokIslm.ElementAt(i).FaturaNo + "' ,'" + stokAsil.StokIslm.ElementAt(i).BagBarkod[j] + @"', '" + stokAsil.StokIslm.ElementAt(i).KoliBarkod[j] + "', '" + stokAsil.StokIslm.ElementAt(i).PaletBarkod[j] + "')";

                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                }
                // Commit the transaction.
                transaction.Commit();
                Console.WriteLine("Bütün Kayıtlar başarı ile eklendi.");
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                MessageBox.Show(" " + ex.Message);
                try
                {
                    // Attempt to roll back the transaction.
                    transaction.Rollback();
                }
                catch
                {
                    // Do nothing here; transaction is not active.
                }
            }
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: hi! you have to provide a more simplified version of your code, to help reproduce your problem! Also, do explain a bit more of the error you get. Provide some error output or something like that.

Comment: are you sure you use OLE DB (www.ibprovider.com) rather than more usual for C# .Net Provider ?

Comment: The way you splice values into command string is poor - it is both fragile (dangerous of data type errors and SQL injections - see http://bobby-tables.com/ ) and slow (needs all the commands to be parsed and re-parsed and re-parsed yet again). Try to rewrite your code to use `parameters` and to `prepare` your command once before the loop. Inside the loop you only change (with type safety) parameter values and execute the already pre-prepared query. The examples of using transactions in OLE DB shows how to supply TX to the commands constructors.

Comment: https://www.ibprovider.com/eng/documentation/lcpi_oledb_net__using_adonet_with_firebird.html#m5_2 The same article in `Commands with parameters` section shows how you are expected to pass the data values in a safe way.

Comment: I don't get any error.

Comment: if you have no error then it is totally unclear what exactly you don't like in your program's behavior. https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html

Comment: How do you know that the result is not committed? Make sure that you start a fresh transaction in whatever you are using to check the result. Depending on the transaction isolation levels, a transaction may not see changes committed after that transaction started.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously a lot for you to try and take in.  Suggested sources to look might appear intimidating.  You may have to tweak this some, but SHOULD get you going.

Since you did make a sincere effort, I have provded update for you to follow and hopefully you can still read-up on Sql-Injection and prevention methods.

```
// Set the Connection to the new OleDbConnection.
command.Connection = connection;

// Open the connection and execute the transaction.
try
{
    connection.Open();

    // Start a local transaction
    transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

    // Assign transaction object for a pending local transaction.
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.Transaction = transaction;

    // Execute the commands.
    command.CommandText =
    @"INSERT INTO STOKASIL 
    (   STOK_ISLEMA_NO,
        ISLEM_KODU, 
        ISLEM_YONU, 
        ISLEM_ADI, 
        GIRIS_CARI_NO, 
        CIKIS_CARI_NO, 
        GIRIS_STOK_YERI_NO,
        CIKIS_STOK_YERI_NO, 
        GIRIS_ISLEM_NOKTASI_NO, 
        CIKIS_ISLEM_NOKTASI_NO, 
        GIRIS_PERSONEL_NO, 
        CIKIS_PERSONEL_NO,
        FATURA_NO,
        TARIH )
    VALUES
    (   ?,
        'STKGİR', 
        1, 
        'Stok Girişi', 
        ?, 
        ?, 
        ?, 
        ?, 
        ?,
        ?, 
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        CURRENT_DATE ) ";

    // NOW, Add the parameters.  Via OleDB, parameters are typically found with "?" as a place-holder 
    // for a corresponding parameter and MUST be added  to the query command in same sequence.
    // others may complain about using AddWithValue, but simplified to show context of order as I dont know your data type values (string, int, decimal, date, etc)

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmSTOK_ISLEMA_NO", stokAsil.IslemANo );

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmGIRIS_CARI_NO", stokAsil.GirisCariNo );
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmCIKIS_CARI_NO", stokAsil.CikisCariNo );

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmGIRIS_STOK_YERI_NO", stokAsil.GirisStokYeriNo );
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmCIKIS_STOK_YERI_NO", stokAsil.CikisStokYeriNo );

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmGIRIS_ISLEM_NOKTASI_NO", stokAsil.GirisIslemNoktasiNo );
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmCIKIS_ISLEM_NOKTASI_NO", stokAsil.CikisIslemNoktasiNo );

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmGIRIS_PERSONEL_NO", stokAsil.GirisPersonelNo );
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmCIKIS_PERSONEL_NO", stokAsil.CikisPersonelNo );

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmFATURA_NO", stokAsil.FaturaNo );


    // NOW we can insert.
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();


    // Now, for the next one in the loop, prepare a new command and its parameters ONCE.
    var cmdIns1 = new OleDbCommand();
    cmdIns1.Connection = connection;
    cmdIns1.Transaction = transaction;
    cmdIns1.CommandText = 
    @"INSERT INTO STOKISLM
    (   STOK_ISLEMA_NO, 
        ISLEM_KODU, 
        ISLEM_ADI, 
        ISLEM_YONU, 
        TARIH,STOK_YERI_NO, 
        CARI_NO, 
        PERSONEL_NO, 
        ISLEM_NOKTASI_NO, 
        STOK_NO, 
        BIRIM,
        BIRIMX,
        MIKTAR, 
        DSTOK_NO, 
        DOVIZ_BIRIMI, 
        DOVIZ_KURU, 
        TAKIP_SEKLI, 
        FSTOK_URET )
    VALUES
    (   ?, 
        'STKGİR',
        'Stok Girişi', 
        1, 
        CURRENT_DATE,
        ?, 
        ?, 
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        (SELECT FIRST 1 BIRIM 
            FROM STOKBIRI 
            WHERE STOK_NO =  ?
            ORDER BY SIRA_NO), 
        (SELECT FIRST 1 BIRIMX 
            FROM STOKBIRI 
            WHERE STOK_NO = ? 
            ORDER BY SIRA_NO),
        ?, 
        0, 
        'TL', 
        1, 
        'M', 
        'E' )";

    // Now, to prepare the parameters here, I am pre-pulling the first instance from your list
    // so the parmeters have proper data types in them.  People may complain about using. Same concept
    var tmpRecord = stokAsil.StokIslm.ElementAt(0);

    // uses the "stokAsil" from parent insert transaction basis record
    cmdIns1.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmSTOK_ISLEMA_NO", stokAsil.IslemANo );

    // Now use the per-element temporary record
    cmdIns1.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmSTOK_YERI_NO", tmpRecord.StokYeriNo);
    cmdIns1.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmCARI_NO", tmpRecord.CariNo);
    cmdIns1.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmPERSONEL_NO", tmpRecord.PersonelNo);
    cmdIns1.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmISLEM_NOKTASI_NO", tmpRecord.IslemNoktasıNo);
    cmdIns1.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmSTOK_NO", tmpRecord.StokNo);
    // this is parameter placement within the insert's SUBQUERY, same value, just required placement of parameter to qualify
    cmdIns1.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmQry1STOK_NO", tmpRecord.StokNo);
    // same for second Subquery
    cmdIns1.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmQry2STOK_NO", tmpRecord.StokNo);
    cmdIns1.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmMIKTAR", tmpRecord.Miktar);

    cmdIns1.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmDSTOK_NO", tmpRecord.StokYeriNo);
    cmdIns1.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmDOVIZ_BIRIMI", tmpRecord.StokYeriNo);
    cmdIns1.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmDOVIZ_KURU", tmpRecord.StokYeriNo);
    cmdIns1.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmTAKIP_SEKLI", tmpRecord.StokYeriNo);
    cmdIns1.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmFSTOK_URET", tmpRecord.StokYeriNo);


    // Since you have a nested transaction and additional insert into other table,
    // similarly prepare a seperate command for it so it does not have to keep being rebuilt
    var cmdIns2 = new OleDbCommand();
    cmdIns2.Connection = connection;
    cmdIns2.Transaction = transaction;
    cmdIns2.CommandText = 
@"INSERT INTO STOKCEKI 
(   STOK_ISLEM_NO, 
    TAKIP_NO,
    SIRA_NO,
    MIKTAR,
    BIRIM, 
    ACIKLAMA2,
    ACIKLAMA3,
    ACIKLAMA4,
    ACIKLAMA5 )
VALUES
(   ?, 
    ?,
    ?,
    ?, 
    'Adet',
    ?,
    ?, 
    ?, 
    ? )";

    // still tmp object place-holder
    tmpRecord = stokAsil.StokIslm.ElementAt(0);

    cmdIns2.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmSTOK_ISLEM_NO", tmpRecord.StokIslemNo);
    cmdIns2.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmTAKIP_NO", tmpRecord.TakipNo.ElementAt(0) ); 
    // Just a place-holder integer value for the "j + 1" value
    cmdIns2.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmSIRA_NO", 1 );
    cmdIns2.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmMIKTAR", tmpRecord.Miktar);

    cmdIns2.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmACIKLAMA2", tmpRecord.FaturaNo);
    // temporary forcing "j" subscript to 0 just for place-holder value of parameter
    cmdIns2.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmACIKLAMA3", tmpRecord.BagBarkod[0] );
    cmdIns2.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmACIKLAMA4", tmpRecord.KoliBarkod[0] );
    cmdIns2.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmACIKLAMA5 ", tmpRecord.PaletBarkod[0] );

    // Now the second insert command is prepared too



    // NOW, we can start the loop with the prepared sql command and parameters.
    for (int i = 0; i < stokAsil.StokIslm.Count; i++)
    {
        // to keep inline with the command parameters added, 
        // re-set the tmpRecord to the specific element at you are trying to work with.
        tmpRecord = stokAsil.StokIslm.ElementAt(i);

        // As for the parameters, we don't need to add them again, just need to 
        // UPDATE the PARAMETER's VALUE based on the actual cycle record... doing in same order
        // we CAN skip the first parameter as that is a constant for all, but you COULD if you wanted to
        cmdIns1.Parameters["parmSTOK_ISLEMA_NO"].Value =  stokAsil.IslemANo;

        // Now the rest per the actual record being processed
        cmdIns1.Parameters["parmSTOK_YERI_NO"].Value = tmpRecord.StokYeriNo;
        cmdIns1.Parameters["parmCARI_NO"].Value = tmpRecord.CariNo;
        cmdIns1.Parameters["parmPERSONEL_NO"].Value = tmpRecord.PersonelNo;
        cmdIns1.Parameters["parmISLEM_NOKTASI_NO"].Value = tmpRecord.IslemNoktasıNo;
        cmdIns1.Parameters["parmSTOK_NO"].Value = tmpRecord.StokNo;
        cmdIns1.Parameters["parmQry1STOK_NO"].Value = tmpRecord.StokNo;
        cmdIns1.Parameters["parmQry2STOK_NO"].Value = tmpRecord.StokNo;
        cmdIns1.Parameters["parmMIKTAR"].Value = tmpRecord.Miktar;
        cmdIns1.Parameters["parmDSTOK_NO"].Value = tmpRecord.StokYeriNo;
        cmdIns1.Parameters["parmDOVIZ_BIRIMI"].Value = tmpRecord.StokYeriNo;
        cmdIns1.Parameters["parmDOVIZ_KURU"].Value = tmpRecord.StokYeriNo;
        cmdIns1.Parameters["parmTAKIP_SEKLI"].Value = tmpRecord.StokYeriNo;
        cmdIns1.Parameters["parmFSTOK_URET"].Value = tmpRecord.StokYeriNo;

        // NOW you can execute the query with parameters in place for it
        cmdIns1.ExecuteNonQuery();

        for (int j = 0; j < stokAsil.StokIslm.ElementAt(i).TakipNo.Count(); j++)
        {
            // similarly, setting the "VALUE" of each parameter from current actual record object/counter
            cmdIns2.Parameters["parmSTOK_ISLEM_NO", tmpRecord.StokIslemNo);
            // NOW we can use the "j" subscipt reference
            cmdIns2.Parameters["parmTAKIP_NO"].Value = tmpRecord.TakipNo.ElementAt(j) ); 
            cmdIns2.Parameters["parmSIRA_NO"].Value = j+1 );
            cmdIns2.Parameters["parmMIKTAR"].Value = tmpRecord.Miktar);

            cmdIns2.Parameters["parmACIKLAMA2"].Value = tmpRecord.FaturaNo);
            cmdIns2.Parameters["parmACIKLAMA3"].Value = tmpRecord.BagBarkod[j] );
            cmdIns2.Parameters["parmACIKLAMA4"].Value = tmpRecord.KoliBarkod[j] );
            cmdIns2.Parameters["parmACIKLAMA5"].Value = tmpRecord.PaletBarkod[j] );

            // NOW we can insert second cycle of records
            cmdIns2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    // Commit the transaction.
    transaction.Commit();
    Console.WriteLine("Bütün Kayıtlar başarı ile eklendi.");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    MessageBox.Show(" " + ex.Message);
    try
    {
        // Attempt to roll back the transaction.
        transaction.Rollback();
    }
    catch
    {
        // Do nothing here; transaction is not active.
    }
}
```